# Remove elements from one Hashset where NOT in another Hashset?

Tags: c#, hashset

I am aware of `hashsetA.Except(hashsetB)` to remove elements from `hashsetA` that exist in `hashsetB`. However, I want to remove elements from `hashsetA` that **don't** exist in `hashsetB`.

Currently I just copy `hashsetA` to a new `Hashset` then use `ExceptWith()` twice:

```
hashsetC = new HashSet<var>(hashsetA);
hashsetC.ExceptWith(hashsetB);
hashsetA.ExceptWith(hashsetC);
```

The performance of this is plenty good enough for my purposes, but I was wondering if there's a built in method to make this faster/more concise?
Or am I missing an obvious way to select from the sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`IntersectWith` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx).

```
hashsetA.IntersectWith(hashsetB);
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you! My set theory is clearly very rusty to not spot an intersect when it's needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
res = hashsetA.Where(p=> hashsetB.Contains(p)).
```

Given that lookup in a Hashset is O(1), that should sum to O(n).

Comment: It creates `res`, but I think the asker wants to modify `hashsetA`. You do not explain how to achieve that. Doing `new HashSet<var>(res)` will give another set, but not modify `hashsetA`. Then `hashsetA = new HashSet<var>(res)` where `res` is from your answer *might* be helpful, but not if other people have references to the original instance of `HashSet<>`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes I agree, if it's necessary to modify an existing hashset then your solution is the correct one :)

Comment: If you want to use Linq to "filter" the collection without changing the source, you can also use `res = hashsetA.Intersect(hashsetB);`.